# Open torrent ports in csf

Tags: firewall, csf, bittorrent

I use aria2 on my office with debian linux and aria2web to download some torrents on that. in brief it's a torrent client. but if i turn on csf, aria2c can't do that.

which config should i do for csf ? which ports in TCP or UDP should i open to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Csf seams to block the ports used by torrent client. To unblock them edit your /etc/csf/csf.conf by adding or editing the line

```
TCP_IN = port1, port2, port3:port4
```

Check your torrent-client settings to define used ports.

Comment: i found torrent ports.